# iOS can i build an app or service to keep bluetooth discover device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, push-notification, bluetooth-lowenergy

if discover a new device then push notification to the user.
how to start and any resources/sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three previous answers are incorrect. iOS5 introduced [Core Bluetooth framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html).

However, **this framework is BT 4.0 LE only**; none-the-less Bluetooth.

Here also is the PDF reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/CoreBluetooth_Framework.pdf

### Example

Your class must conform to the **`CBCentralManagerDelegate`** and **`CBPeripheralDelegate`** protocols.

```
CBCentralManager * btCentral = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

/* Create an array of services from a CBUUID to scan for */
[btCentral scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
```

That's basically to get you started on scanning for peripherals. You will also need to implement the **`CBCentralManagerDelegate`** methods and a few others, I suggest reading the docs:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals
```

Comment: How about build it as a service, can i trigger the bluetooth discovery  in background at the iphone normal state (not enter the app). I can discovery device now, mainly i would like the bluetooth running all the time, even it is back to HOME (not in app inside)

Comment: After some time, your app may become inactive, at which point, no.